# How to make a CSS animation slow to a stop on hover out?

Tags: css

I have a CSS animation that rotates a div infinitely when I hover over it. The CSS looks something like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#square {
    background-color: #369;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#square:hover {
    -webkit-animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
}
```

The problem that I'm trying to solve is that when I hover out, it abruptly jumps back to its original state. This can be jarring when it's in the middle of the animation. Is there a way to ***slowly*** transition back to the original state? Normally, you can do that sort of thing with transitions, but it doesn't seem to work in conjunction with animations. For example, I tried adding `-webkit-transition: all 2s;` to the `#square` selector in the example above, but it didn't do anything.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/93jeS/

Answer (score 4):

I spent a few hours on this one and think I've finally got it.

Here is a link to the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ToddNewent/awbbnbw1/)

Essentially `#square` gets the CSS attribute of `animation-name:rotate;` added to it on hover to initiate the infinite rotation. Then another function that fires on a `mouseout` adds an event listener to `animationiteration` so that when the animation iterates it can cease the rotation. To end the rotation the `#square` gets the CSS attribute of `animation-name:none;`. Finally, `#square` is replaced with a clone of itself to allow the behaviour to repeat after it has been through one cycle of the `hover` and `mouseout`.

```
$('#square').hover(function() {
  $(this).css('-webkit-animation-name', 'rotate');
});

$('#square').mouseout(function() {
  $(this).on('animationiteration', function() {
    $(this).css('-webkit-animation-name', 'none');
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).clone(true));
  });
});
```

**Additionally**

[This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ToddNewent/m4rwdLc1/) though slightly temperamental may be a partial solution to adding a nice ease-out effect. I just modified the CSS with a :hover selector to toggle the linear and ease-out attributes.